# OpenOffice.org Defective JRE

Tags: ubuntu, java, openoffice

I installed the ODT to LaTex converter for OpenOffice under Ubuntu 9.04 because I wanted to convert my basic document template and even though it found the proper Sun JRE (Version is 1.6.0_14, ddisplayed under Tools -> Options -> OpenOffice.org / Java) and the OO Java package has been installed it still gives me this error message:

OpenOffice.org requires a Java runtime einvornment (JRE) to perform this task. The selected JRE is defective....

I ran out of ideas on how to fix this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the solutions mentioned in this [thread](http://user.services.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=16&t=5463):

- Close OOo and delete the `~/.openoffice.org/3/user/config/javasettings_Linux_x86.xml` file
- If that didn't work, rename your OOo user profile (`~/.openoffice.org`)

If these don't work, look through the thread for a number of other workarounds. This bug report also seems relevant to your issue: [Stream of JRE errors when going to "Macros" tab in frame properties](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openoffice.org/+bug/149489)

Answer (score 0):

Does it require "a" JRE or "that" JRE? Cus couldn't you just install another Java environment and it'll work?